# SQL Combining two tables with one same column without losing values of a different one

Tags: sql

I've been struggling with this for a while, I have two different tables that share a column but both have different amount of rows.
One of the tables is for money requests (table 1) and the other one is for proving the expenses (table 2)

#### Table 1

```
+-----------+-----------+
|expenseid  | requestid |
+-----------+-----------+
| 16333     | 7454      |
| NULL      | 7455      |
| 16336     | 7456      |
| 16338     | 7457      |
| NULL      | 7458      |
| 16341     | 7459      |
| 16345     | 7460      |
| NULL      | 7461      |
| NULL      | 7462      |
+-----------+-----------+
```

#### Table 2

```
+-----------+-----------+
|expenseid  | amount    |
+-----------+-----------+
| 16333     | 200       |
| 16334     | 150       |
| 16335     | 300       |
| 16336     | 900       |
| 16337     | 100       |
| 16338     | 120       |
| 16339     | 700       |
| 16340     | 431       |
| 16341     | 420       |
| 16342     | 150       |
| 16343     | 240       |
| 16344     | 465       |
| 16345     | 200       |
| 16346     | 120       |
| 16347     | 90        |
| 16348     | 50        |
| 16349     | 245       |
+-----------+-----------+
```

As you can see the tables share the same column 'expenseid', but the amount of rows is different and there are two different columns that don't correspond to each other, i would like to have a table as follows

#### Combined table

```
+-----------+-----------+-----------+
|expenseid  | amount    | requestid | 
+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| 16333     | 200       | 7454      |
| NULL      | NULL      | 7455      |
| 16334     | 150       | NULL      |
| 16335     | 300       | NULL      |
| 16336     | 900       | 7456      |
| 16337     | 100       | NULL      |
| 16338     | 120       | 7457      |
| NULL      | NULL      | 7458      |
| 16339     | 700       | NULL      |
| 16340     | 431       | NULL      |
| 16341     | 420       | 7459      |
| 16342     | 150       | NULL      |
| 16343     | 240       | NULL      |
| 16344     | 465       | NULL      |
| 16345     | 200       | 7460      |
| NULL      | NULL      | 7461      |
| NULL      | NULL      | 7462      |
| 16346     | 120       | NULL      |
| 16347     | 90        | NULL      |
| 16348     | 50        | NULL      |
| 16349     | 245       | NULL      |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+
```

I've managed to merge both tables in a way it shows the null values for expenseid related to table 1 with a left outer join, but it doesn't show the null values for the column requestid, any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: select * from table1, table2   ?

Answer (score 2):

You need a [`FULL OUTER JOIN`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Full_outer_join) instead of a `LEFT OUTER JOIN`.

```
SELECT
    COALESCE(Table1.expenseid, Table2.expenseid) AS expenseid,
    amount,
    requestid
FROM Table1
FULL OUTER JOIN Table2
ON Table1.expenseid = Table2.expenseid
```

Results:

```
EXPENSEID   AMOUNT  REQUESTID
16333       200     7454
(null)      (null)  7455
16336       900     7456
16338       120     7457
...etc...
```

See it working online: [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d8951/3)

Comment: I've tried doing a FULL OUTER JOIN but it does the same thing as the LEFT OUTER JOIN, I'm using SQL Server to do this

Comment: @EdnaRamirez: Can you post the query you tried? It sounds like you are doing something wrong.

Comment: SELECT r.requestid as requestid, e.expenseid  as expenseid, e.amount as amount FROM expenses e
FULL OUTER JOIN requests r ON e.expenseid=r.expenseid

Comment: @EdnaRamirez: The only difference from my query that I can see is that you aren't using COALESCE.